# Is there any working graphical tool to generate nagios user-supplied map coordinates to hosts?

Tags: nagios, network-monitoring, graphical-user-interface, networking

Is there any working graphical tool to generate nagios user-supplied map coordinates to hosts? Or is there any simple way to do by script or manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's not exactly what you ask for but with [NagVis](http://www.nagvis.org/) you could easy create PowerPoint like network maps.

Another way would be to set the parent of each host correctly. Afterwards the automatic status map should be ok.

If you use Linux you could try [Nagios 2D Status Map Editor](http://www.monitoringexchange.org/cgi-bin/page.cgi?g=2101.html;d=1) too.

Comment: NO its not OK. It is simply unusable.

Comment: Nagios 2D Status Map Editor does not work good too..

Comment: But NagVis seems very interesting.